# Halachic Literature on Armory

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot

I have a fairly strong interest in the Armory* and I am aware of the existence of rishonic teshuvot on the subject (see [this article](https://www.heraldica.org/topics/right.htm) on Heraldica). However, as the source is written by a non-Jewish author and is merely making oblique reference as proof that non-Jews were permitted to be armigers (by virtue of poskim permitting Jews to bear arms, which would be unlikely were it illegal), I don't know what his makor is.

Is there any work which discusses armory in halachic literature and the history of psak on the matter ?

---

*The Western heraldic tradition, not to be confused with "armoury," a storage location for weapons and armour.

Comment: "permitting Jews to bear arms" also not to be confused with the 2nd amendment

Comment: @Heshy, clearly, as I expect that the latter would not be relevant in that period and a dup of other questions here

Comment: Do you mean, for example, teshuvot concerning wearing a decorative ruby-studded scabbord on Shabbat?

Comment: @JoshK, please read my footnote, which specifically deals with what you ask